# Transfer searchbar from landing page to navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to achieve is that I want the searchbar from my home.html.erb placed into my _navbar.html.erb

Unfortunately, copy paste is not working (what a suprise!), so I tried creating a controller for my navbar. The problem is, that my _navbar.html.erb is in a shared folder and appears on every page whereas my home.html.erb is only a single page with a PagesController.

The error I'm getting is:

> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

The error appears on the second line of the home.html.erb

My navbar view is in the shared folder like this:

view

- shared
  -> _footer.html.erb
  -> _navbar.html.erb
- pages
  -> home.html.erb

This is my searchbar in home.html.erb

```
<div class="search-bar">
  <%= simple_form_for [@books], url: books_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, required: false, placeholder: "Title or Author", label: false %>
      <%= simple_fields_for :users do |r| %>
        <%= r.input :university, required: false, placeholder: "University", label: false %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'search', class: "btn" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this my PagesController for the home.html.erb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :home
  def home
    @books = Book.new
  end
end
```

This is my attempted Controller for the shared folder

```
class SharedController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :navbar
  def navbar
    @books = Book.new
  end
end
```

Now the most important thing where I also had difficulties,
the routes

```
root to: 'pages#home'
get 'navbar' => 'shared#navbar'
```

I also tried using _navbar instead of just navbar.

Comment: on which line `undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass` error occurred? and if its due to partial file then provide full path `shared/navbar`

Comment: To confirm, do you want your search bar to appear on any page, as the nav bar does? And you ultimately want to be searching your books, regardless of the page you are on?

Comment: Yes, it should be appearing on every page for now, it should be part of the navbar

Comment: Of course, if there is a way that this only appears on specific pages, I am more than eager to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to the error you received: Simple Form tries to discern the model name from the record object (e.g., `@books`) you pass to the `simple_form_for` method (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb)

Because your routing and controller aren't correctly wired up, as you pointed out, Simple Form can't trace `@books` back to a model. However, I have some other recommendations to resolve this error and refactor what I believe you're trying to accomplish:

---

I would recommend putting the search bar erb in a partial sine you have it available on multiple pages. That way you can call it where you want to call it from a view rather than a controller (whether that's always in the nav, or someplace else).

The thing to remember with partials though is that you need to pass through any variables used in the partial when you call it.

For example:

`render partial: 'shared/search_bar', books: @books`

That means that whatever you called the partial from should also have `@books` at some time.

Any easy way to make `@books` available to all views to begin with (instead of passing it around) is to define it in your `ApplicationController`class.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :book_collection

  def book_collection
    @books = Book.all
  end
end
```

Then you can call just `render partial: 'shared/search_bar'`, and in your search form, pass in `book_collection`.

---

In a similar vein, I don't think you need to define a route and controller action for your nav bar. I imagine a nav bar is repeated code that appears on all pages, which again feels like a partial. By the way, you have already named your files correctly as partials, with the underscore!

You could call the navbar partial in your application layout to have it appear on every page:

`views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<body>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/navbar' %>
# you could also call the search bar here, if books is available from application controller and you want it on every page, otherwise call it on the pages you want:
  <%= render partial: 'shared/search_bar' %>
</body>
```

All that being said, I am curious about how your search bar is wired up once a user submits a search. I am not sure that you need to pass an instance variable. I recommend checking out this guide on including a simple search form in your Rails application: http://www.rymcmahon.com/articles/2

Answer (score 0):

If you have views with `_name`, they are used for `render form.html.erb` for example. So routes and Controller doesn't find it, I would say. So try it with render function or work over your views and their names.

Also `simple_form_for @books` should be more rigth?! or do you need to Array your @books :P

Comment: ok ill try that. And the simpe_form_for @books is alright. The searchbar itself is working wihout a problem